# Can I use the options parameter in Backbone.js's model.validate() function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone.js lets me extend a model's validate function with the prototype: `validate: function (attrs, options) { ... }`.

What I want to do is be able to perform some tests *only* when a certain option is passed into the options parameter. I have tried calling `model.isValid({specialCheck: true})` and checking `options.specialCheck` in the validate function, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
validate: function(attrs, options) {
  if(options.specialCheck) {
    // Perform special checks
    ...
  }
  // Perform regular checks
  ...
}
```

What is the `options` parameter and how can I use it? Or do I have to find some other workaround (setting a flag on a model, etc.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qYp7x/2/)) works:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend( {
    validate : function( attrs, options ) {
        if( options.specialValidation ) {
            alert("is special");
        }
        else {
            alert("is not special");
        }
    }
});

var m = new MyModel();

m.isValid({ specialValidation : true });
```

Comment: Thanks! I just assumed this wasn't working but it was another condition in my check that wasn't correct.